# Rust: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm having a problem when compiling using cargo build/run that seems to happen if i have Strings or Vecs (possibly other things too) in the code.

for example, this works just fine:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "hello world";
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

now if i run this:

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("hello world");
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

i get this error:

```
Compiling idk v0.1.0 (C:\Users\berna\OneDrive\Área de 

Trabalho\Coisas Aleatórias\Rust\idk)
error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--dynamicbase" "-Wl,--disable-auto-image-base" "-m64" "-Wl,--high-entropy-va" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsbegin.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustccQRrIz\\symbols.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.13std4231fj0gult.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.17nlusf8m4o5p6np.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.1ehxeerjthawqhie.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.1o99ezexjri9e12r.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.1rqbhjilap06n351.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.1ttc612ut3k96t4.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.1uh5mhe7ecjr7d7q.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.1won7galjg5og26k.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.20sbwlfxjexaodw3.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.26wlm8o95uex8lxv.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.28be5d6n9utm38wq.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.2j87avxhmpffqwga.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.2mz9rwaummyimcuk.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.31znni608yp266ff.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.3b7avn4cpb67a91f.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.3fgfpd98tcyopzpp.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.3h1t3knccb0q11yy.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.3ppqv957mqi7qdo.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.3ts47qqojub71rx2.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.3xciqeqeqwith2zg.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.4diuv7f48b3z11fd.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.4jklba9a1x0jyaym.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.4jq8gd45x33jrvmf.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.4re8a6787bt8kxo0.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.4sb6ft2jnrcakqa3.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.4u74unmd4qk9a0k0.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.5adfcawix6uiyfk6.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.5ewqxki7mwrygoht.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.69qevk6btpzuxys.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.8tddpzcxjdh3p4v.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.9vnrvy51cmi8cox.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.iw0woep5794gv4h.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.jnix3goxvt74c7n.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.juiy09kec2gtb9k.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.m19xoq8guqu4sr1.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.n39t3khb9i7r9zw.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.nak7x162nki2ug1.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.nkbhsv7x4w5rspz.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.540zrj573cg793i.rcgu.o" "-L" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps" "-L" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd-286d92372824ad75.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-98fbfa7e7941eb44.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libobject-9ce2fc6f473084c9.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libmemchr-60c7a9ccebc1c0df.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libaddr2line-a6c791f82a11d981.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libgimli-82449fe6dba22989.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_demangle-a0bb6c42cb40e3b2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd_detect-aff674fba5d55355.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libhashbrown-3acaef96bbb1962c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libminiz_oxide-38836d23dc28fffc.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libadler-3e94f58c71461bb0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-8694d78ac5d3c596.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libunwind-f971c060b6355776.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcfg_if-cb8714f793b7f21c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liblibc-06ac00fc59f0c9ac.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc-67bebcf125a98a92.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-120164796f318db1.rlib" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcore-c926020a7e02cde7.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-50eb72b9dd1763b8.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-ladvapi32" "-luserenv" "-lkernel32" "-lws2_32" "-lbcrypt" "-lgcc_eh" "-l:libpthread.a" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-L" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-o" "C:\\Users\\berna\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\Coisas Aleatórias\\Rust\\idk\\target\\debug\\deps\\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.exe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie" "-nodefaultlibs" "C:\\Users\\berna\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsend.o"
  = note: c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file C:\Users\berna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Coisas Aleatórias\Rust\idk\target\debug\deps\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.exe: No such file or directory
          collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: could not compile `idk` due to previous error
```

this doesn't happen with rustc, only cargo.

edit: spelling

Comment: Can you try it in a folder without special characters? In particular there are several ways that "ò" can be represented in UTF-16 and I don't know what Windows does if different encodings are mixed.

Comment: that was it! which makes no sense to me, cause i had rust working fine on a directory with "ó" before, but now it just decided that it won't work anymore..
I guess I can't use rust on desktop then.
Anyway, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`cannot open output file C:\...\target\debug\deps\idk-6b1a842651530e3e.exe: No such file or directory`

I don't have personal experience with this problem, but I've heard of several incidents where this indicated a virus scanner deciding that your newly created executable is suspicious and deleting it. To avoid the problem, exclude your `target` directory from scanning.

Comment: Unfortunately is not that, the entire folder was already excluded and I also tried with the antivirus deactivated but no success ._.

Answer (score 0):

For all my foreign people finding for an answer, see if you have an accent in your project, it definetly breaks your compilation (in case you didn't see the comment on the OP)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).